# voltage output at digital pins vs. load

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, voltage-level

I am trying to convert the signal from digital pin 2 on my Uno to 3.3V.  I set up a voltage divider with 3 x 1000 ohm resistors.  When connected to ground and 5V the divider circuit generates 3.3V correctly, with a calculated input current of 1.7mA.  However I connect it to a digital pin, the digital pin voltage drops from 4.8V to .37V.  I thought the digital pins were to support 40mA, I was assuming 40mA at the 5V supply voltage.  Is my Uno malfunctioning?

Thanks

Comment: Sure you got the pin set up as an output and have written a high/1 to it? (have to ask). What's on the output of the voltage divider - i.e. between the resistors? Something with a high/low resistance/impedance?

Comment: Just figured out I didn't have the pin mode set, it works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out I didn't have the pin mode set, it works fine now, thanks.